# Interpreting Procdump Exception code 00000006, and the difference between E06D7363.J and E06D7363.msc

Tags: c++, exception, seh, procdump

I am analyzing a dump file of a c++ application, generated by `ProcDump`. 
The log file generated by `ProcDump` contains tons of `Exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION`
which are easily understandable as Access Violations.

However I have not managed to understand the meaning of those `00000006`:

- `[15:39:59] Exception: 00000006`

Secondly, although I've found that `E06D7363` means C++ exception, I have not managed to find the difference between `Exception: E06D7363.J` and `Exception: E06D7363.msc`. Is there any difference ?

Comment: That doesn't mean much of anything.  Just locate the first exception and treat any after it as shrapnel from a badly corrupted process.

Comment: Of course. But I thought `Exception: 00000006` could give me some more information about what is happening.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea, but maybe `MSC` stands for _MicroSoft C++_ and `J` stands for _Java_. IIRC, C++ and Java exceptions used to be somewhat similar under the SEH hood.

Comment: I really don't think we have java component in this application, but I'm gonna check if ever.

Comment: About the `00000006`, since `C0000006` is `IN_PAGE_ERROR`, and the `C0000000` means more or less "system error", I'm guessing that it is a non-fatal page-fault, probably from the stack probing.